# symfony 1.4 - route based on user type

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

i've been using symfony 1.4 to build a project that i didn't quite think through all the way.  the site has four user types: A, B, C, and users who aren't authenticated.  i need for each user type to have their own set of routing and actions.  when a user of type A visits mysite.com/ he will see something different than users who are B's, C's, and not logged in.  A users might also have these routes available to them: mysite.com/users, mysite.com/groups, etc., whereas B's, C's, and non-authenticated users might not.  basically, sometimes users might share some routes (like /), and sometimes they won't.

symfony unfortunately loads the routing before it hits the user filter, and as far as i can tell there's no easy way to repopulate the routing on the fly and redispatch.  using switchTo also seems horribad because i'd essentially be loading the application twice for each request.

basically i need the framework to look at the users type and load the appropriate routing.  any solutions involving symfony are desperately welcome!  D:

Answer (score 0):

Think about your application design. URLs are identifiers to Objects. It's not a good design to use the same URL for different things.

Maybe if the type of Users are really different you can also consider to create different apps for the interfaces. Then you can also create different session cookies.

URLS can then be
/ the frontpage
/groups the group page for all normal users
/admin/groups administration interface for groups

Comment: Some ideas to consider: different login forms, links to the other app, http redirect.

Comment: having each user type as a separate app was actually was i first tried.  i ran into the problem of inter app routing, mainly because of logging in and out.  redirection is fine, there's a nice plugin called swInterAppRouting (or something), however there's still no inter-app forwarding.

so basically, all user's logout links were a link that redirected to the default/logout action, which seemed okay.  however, with logging in it's more gross, because they'd login, submit the post, and after it processed the login it would need to do an inter-app redirect, which is just sloppy.

Comment: all symfony documentation that i've seen are projects built on the two app paradigm, and it looks like only one app at a time can use the index.php frontcontroller (the one that would be invisible and keep things 'pretty').  so that means that i can choose one user app to have 'pretty' urls for while the others would be forced to have some sort of '/user_x.php/' controller in the url, which i don't want.

basically you're right, it makes sense for them to be separate apps, but i at least need each app to be able to interact with the 'default' one.

Comment: you can get rid of `/user_x.php/module/action` urls easily with mod_rewrite